# Jhipster monolithic application error Your request cannot be processed

Tags: jhipster

I generated a monolithic application using jhipster. After creation tried to access http://localhost:8080/. But getting error Your request cannot be processed
I am using JWT authentication (stateless, with a token). Using below command to run applicaiton

```
./mvnw
```

I have enable debug logging as below

```
    <logger name="io.undertow" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="io.undertow.websockets.jsr" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Below is what I observed in logs

```
:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2020-08-28 14:19:30.606  WARN 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.StartupInfoLogger               : InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() took 5006 milliseconds to respond. Please verify your network configuration (macOS machines may need to add entries to /etc/hosts).
2020-08-28 14:19:35.620  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] com.cj.microservices.MonolithicApp       : Starting MonolithicApp on Maheshs-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 3822 
2020-08-28 14:19:35.621 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] com.cj.microservices.MonolithicApp       : Running with Spring Boot v2.2.7.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.6.RELEASE
2020-08-28 14:19:35.621  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] com.cj.microservices.MonolithicApp       : The following profiles are active: dev,swagger
2020-08-28 14:19:37.545  WARN 3822 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2020-08-28 14:19:37.558 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow.session                      : Setting default session timeout to 1800
2020-08-28 14:19:37.567  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-28 14:19:37.567 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2020-08-28 14:19:37.567  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1909 ms
2020-08-28 14:19:37.666 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] i.m.c.u.i.logging.InternalLoggerFactory  : Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2020-08-28 14:19:38.003 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.cj.microservices.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering CORS filter
2020-08-28 14:19:38.036  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.cj.microservices.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2020-08-28 14:19:38.036  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.cj.microservices.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
2020-08-28 14:19:38.040 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow.session                      : Registered session listener io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge@57176fb8
2020-08-28 14:19:38.067 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow.session                      : Setting default session timeout to 1800
2020-08-28 14:19:38.227 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Initialize successful.
2020-08-28 14:19:38.245 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Initialize successful.
2020-08-28 14:19:38.248 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.cj.microservices.domain.User     : Initialize successful.
2020-08-28 14:19:38.251 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.m.domain.Authority             : Initialize successful.
2020-08-28 14:19:38.254 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.m.domain.User.authorities      : Initialize successful.
2020-08-28 14:19:38.269 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.m.config.AsyncConfiguration          : Creating Async Task Executor
2020-08-28 14:19:38.283 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.m.config.LiquibaseConfiguration      : Configuring Liquibase
2020-08-28 14:19:38.419  WARN 3822 --- [nolithic-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2020-08-28 14:19:39.834 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.m.security.jwt.TokenProvider         : Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key
2020-08-28 14:19:40.083 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 1 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-08-28 14:19:40.692 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")) found on specific method: public java.util.List com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.getAuthorities()
2020-08-28 14:19:40.694 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource : Caching method [CacheKey[com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource; public java.util.List com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.getAuthorities()]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2020-08-28 14:19:40.705 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2020-08-28 14:19:40.707 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")) found on specific method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.createUser(com.cj.microservices.service.dto.UserDTO) throws java.net.URISyntaxException
2020-08-28 14:19:40.707 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource : Caching method [CacheKey[com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource; public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.createUser(com.cj.microservices.service.dto.UserDTO) throws java.net.URISyntaxException]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2020-08-28 14:19:40.707 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")) found on specific method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.updateUser(com.cj.microservices.service.dto.UserDTO)
2020-08-28 14:19:40.707 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource : Caching method [CacheKey[com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource; public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.updateUser(com.cj.microservices.service.dto.UserDTO)]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2020-08-28 14:19:40.708 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")) found on specific method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.deleteUser(java.lang.String)
2020-08-28 14:19:40.708 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource : Caching method [CacheKey[com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource; public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.cj.microservices.web.rest.UserResource.deleteUser(java.lang.String)]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2020-08-28 14:19:41.386 DEBUG 3822 --- [nolithic-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 2966 ms
2020-08-28 14:19:41.519 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 23 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2020-08-28 14:19:41.735 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {securityConfiguration=com.cj.microservices.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9b9cb10@5078c229}
2020-08-28 14:19:41.783  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/**', OPTIONS], []
2020-08-28 14:19:41.783  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/swagger-ui/index.html'], []
2020-08-28 14:19:41.783  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/test/**'], []
2020-08-28 14:19:41.826 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/api/authenticate']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.828 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/api/register']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.828 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/api/activate']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.828 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/api/account/reset-password/init']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.828 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/api/account/reset-password/finish']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.828 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for Ant [pattern='/api/**']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.829 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/management/health']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.829 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/management/info']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.829 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/management/prometheus']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.829 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')', for Ant [pattern='/management/**']
2020-08-28 14:19:41.832 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2020-08-28 14:19:41.832 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2020-08-28 14:19:41.842  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6edb1674, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7380c01e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4077fd58, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@37034f72, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@705407b6, com.cj.microservices.security.jwt.JWTFilter@9cd8d0b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3119b323, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@40a22f8a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@19c12ba1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@75b1b7ba, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@53397be6, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4baec252, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3e63cd6d]
2020-08-28 14:19:42.098 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-08-28 14:19:42.156 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2020-08-28 14:19:42.242 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerAutoConfiguration  : Starting Swagger
2020-08-28 14:19:42.250 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerAutoConfiguration  : Started Swagger in 6 ms
2020-08-28 14:19:42.802 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] o.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter  : Filter 'corsFilter' configured for use
2020-08-28 14:19:42.804  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow                              : starting server: Undertow - 2.0.30.Final
2020-08-28 14:19:42.842 DEBUG 3822 --- [  restartedMain] io.undertow                              : Configuring listener with protocol HTTP for interface 0.0.0.0 and port 8080
2020-08-28 14:19:42.880  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] com.cj.microservices.MonolithicApp       : Started MonolithicApp in 27.954 seconds (JVM running for 28.489)
2020-08-28 14:19:47.891  INFO 3822 --- [  restartedMain] com.cj.microservices.MonolithicApp       : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'monolithic' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080/
    External:   http://192.168.1.11:8080/
    Profile(s):     [dev, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-28 14:19:51.830 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] io.undertow.request.security             : Attempting to authenticate /, authentication required: false
2020-08-28 14:19:51.832 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] io.undertow.request.security             : Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.security.impl.CachedAuthenticatedSessionMechanism@28928814 for /
2020-08-28 14:19:51.832 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] io.undertow.request.security             : Authentication result was ATTEMPTED for /
2020-08-28 14:19:51.835  INFO 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.835  INFO 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.835 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-08-28 14:19:51.835 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AngularCookieLocaleResolver
2020-08-28 14:19:51.847 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-08-28 14:19:51.847  INFO 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 12 ms
2020-08-28 14:19:51.858 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'OPTIONS /**'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.859 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/swagger-ui/index.html'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.859 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/test/**'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.860 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.861 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.863 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.864 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.864 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.864 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.864 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.864 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.864 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.865 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.865 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.865 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.865 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2020-08-28 14:19:51.865 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.866 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JWTFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.867 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.867 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.867 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.869 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.870 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3d9ea918: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.871 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.871 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.871 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.871 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/api/authenticate'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/api/register'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/api/activate'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/api/account/reset-password/init'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/api/account/reset-password/finish'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/api/**'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/management/health'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/management/info'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/management/prometheus'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/management/**'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.872 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object - authentication not attempted
2020-08-28 14:19:51.873 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-08-28 14:19:51.875 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2020-08-28 14:19:51.882 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.885 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-08-28 14:19:51.885 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7d053c15
2020-08-28 14:19:51.887 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-08-28 14:19:51.888 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-08-28 14:19:51.888 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-08-28 14:19:51.892 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'OPTIONS /**'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.892 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/swagger-ui/index.html'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/test/**'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.893 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JWTFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3d9ea918: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-08-28 14:19:51.894 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-08-28 14:19:51.897 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2020-08-28 14:19:51.926 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-08-28 14:19:52.191 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2020-08-28 14:19:52.192 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-08-28 14:19:52.192 DEBUG 3822 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Please help

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Updated log file. When you say dev setup, should I run `npm start` and then `./mvnw`?

Comment: I selected no client while generation using JHipster. And in README.md file is as below.
## Development

To start your application in the dev profile, run:

```
./mvnw
```

For further instructions on how to develop with JHipster, have a look at [Using JHipster in development][].

Comment: OK this is a crucial point, you should have said it in your question,we just wasted time.

Comment: Sorry for that. Really appreciate you spending your time in helping me

Comment: Why did you skip the client in first place? You are losing many features and if you plan to develop your own frontend from scratch, you could generate JHipster client in another folder and use it only for development https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/

Comment: I want to build only micro-services for a mobile application. So I thought no need of UI

Comment: If you build microservices, the UI is generated on the gateway and this is where swagger-ui is. Please, next time, give all this information in your question, it will help to help you.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks a lot. After I started exploring JHipster, I am learning more concepts other than just spring micro-serivices. JHipster is not just helping me in building application but also learning new things like histrix, gateway, registry...

Comment: That said, you're not forced to dive in the microservices architecture and the complexity it brings, if you are only building an API server for a mobile, a simple monolith with client generated separately to serve as a backoffice webapp is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generated a server with client code using --skip-client, so what did you expect when accessing `http://localhost:8080/`? Of course, there's no index.html to serve, if you want to do a test you should call the API on `http://localhost:8080/api/<something>`

You don't have swagger-ui because you skipped client, so you should try only a GET in browser or use curl or Postman.

Comment: Is there a way, to set any config to make swagger-ui working?

Comment: Not in JHipster but you can do it manually (worth another question) but it's not that easy because of the authentication that is usually managed by JHipster frontend.